# Resize a View with contentMode .fit

Tags: swiftui, resize, size

I already modified a View in another one with

```
AnotherView ... {
     View()
        .aspectRatio(1.8, contentMode: .fit)
         .cornerRadius(7.2)
... }
```

Now I want to implement AnotherView to a ThirdView, but want to use a flexible Height

```
.frame(minHeight: 0815)
```

of View. But to me it seems like
.aspectRatio(1.8, **contentMode: .fit**)
prevent it. Any ideas to get View flexible without changing AnotherView?

Comment: have you tried using (maxHeight: .infinity) on the third view?

Comment: Yes, I tried it.

Comment: What's happening when you use the code above? Also, when using multiple views like this and trying to figure out the layout, I sometimes find it helpful to give each view a coloured background, that way you can see exactly what's going on. ☺️